# Homestead.yaml format directory path with parenthesis

Tags: yaml, homestead

Getting an error when launching homestead, think it's due to formatting of directory path in Homestead.yaml

```html
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: c:/Users/Charles W/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
        - c:/Users/Charles W/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
        - map: d:/Dropbox (Personal)/code/Homestead/ 
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

I've tried escaping the special characted with `\` and also tried putting `"` around the entire path, and still getting error `C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in 'parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)`

When running `vagrant up` from gitbash on Windows 10

How should I properly format directy path in .yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading as the error is in line 14 actually.

```
folders:
        - map: d:/Dropbox (Personal)/code/Homestead/ 
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

The alignment is wrong, you probably meant

```
folders:
        - map: d:/Dropbox (Personal)/code/Homestead/
          to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Some parsers are able to give you two positions for the error. For example libyaml will tell you:

```
    did not find expected key

was found at document: 1, line: 14, column: 7
while parsing a block mapping at line: 2, column: 1
```

Seems ruby psych just picks one position, and in this case it's the wrong one.

So your problem has nothing to do with escaping. But you might want to read [my article on YAML quoting](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html) anyway.